# Форма, картинки вместо кнопок

Tags: php

Хотел вместо обычных кнопок формы использовать кнопки-картинки. При нажатии кнопки картинки post запрос не срабатывал. как толь image меняю на submit все работает.
Что можно придумать.
И второй вопрос как можно отправить post запрос без формы.  
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Это в каком браузере

   <input type="image" name="text" src="">

не работает?

Comment: "опера" не работает, хром, сафари работает.

Answer (score 4):

**1) Отправить форму:**

- задайте форме name ( `<form name="callback" method="post" action="any.php">` )
- к объекту добавьте: `onclick="document.forms['callback'].submit();"`

Может выглядеть как то так:

```
<form name="callback" method="post" action="any.php">
<input />
<textarea></textarea>
<img src="img.png" alt="send" onclick="document.forms['callback'].submit();" />
</form>
```

Если используете jQuery то ещё проще:

- задаём форме IDшник и просто отправляем так:

  $('#formId').submit();

**2) Возможно отправить post без формы и без перегрузки страницы, при помощи AJAX:**

Как то так:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'feedback.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: 'anydata', 
    success: function(response) { /* success code */ },
    error: function(response) { /* error code */ }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `button` "превратить" в картинку:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить">
```

CSS:

```
input.button {
display: block;
background: url("/images/buttons.png");
width: 188px;
height: 41px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
}

input.button:hover {
color: #FFF;
background-position: 0 -41px; // смещение картинки при наведении
text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

По поводу отправки запроса без формы попробуйте с пом. js:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
        // обработка запроса
});
```

А если с формой, то:

```
$(function () {

    $(".button").click(function () {

        var data = $('.button').parents('form').serialize();

            // делаем ajax запрос
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: data,

                beforeSend: function (html) {
                    // выполнится  до AJAX запроса
                },

                success: function (html) {
                    // выполнится после AJAX запроса
                }
            });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: >> По поводу отправки запроса без формы попробуйте с пом. js:

Это не просто js, а jQuery ;-)

Comment: @Johny, ну да :)

Comment: @NoName то что вы там делали с css обычно через label делается, его собственно для этого и придумали.

Answer (score -5):

просто укажите метод обработки ссылки-картинки POST, это либо один из способов фреймворка, либо на чистом PHP нагуглил так

```
 <?php  
function testLink() { 
$_POST['url'] = "YOYOYO";  
}

?>

<a href='test2.php' onClick='testLink();'>yoyo</a>
```

Comment: Вы из браузера вызываете функцию php?

Comment: Я пошел плакать. Долго и надрывно.

Comment: Ну точно, только сейчас прочитал что не так ) Мне в Rails проще добавлять в link_to параметр method. А на чистом PHP без фреймворков походу такое только через js можно делать.